# Tree of mutable slices

Tags: rust

Some algorithms recursively partition an array into smaller pieces. You can build an explicit binary tree that results from such a process, where each leaf holds a disjoint slice of the array. If you need to alter or reorder elements in the leaf, its slice must be mutable.

```
enum Tree<'a> {
    Branch(Box<[Tree<'a>; 2]>),
    Leaf(&'a mut[f32]),
}
```

Suppose I need to split all the leaves that are larger than some threshold. Easy: recursively walk down the tree from the root; when I find a leaf with a slice long enough, split it into 2 halves, wrap them into a 2-leaf subtree, and replace the leaf.

```
impl<'a> Tree<'a> {
    fn split(&mut self, max: usize) {
        match self {
            &mut Tree::Branch(ref mut trees) => {
                trees[0].split(max);
                trees[1].split(max);
            },
            &mut Tree::Leaf(ref mut leaf) if leaf.len() > max => {
                let mid = leaf.len() / 2;
                let (l, r) = leaf.split_at_mut(mid);
                let trees = [Tree::Leaf(l), Tree::Leaf(r)];
                *self = Tree::Branch(Box::new(trees));
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the borrow-checker is unable to find a suitable lifetime for the `ref mut leaf` pattern. It wants it dead before allowing the assignement to `*self`, but I don't see how to make the assignment out of the match arm.

How to make this work?

Comment: This might be useful: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html. I didn't look at your requirement in detail but `slice.split_at_mut()` is likely what you need.

Comment: Indeed, I use it in the second match arm!

Comment: Oh! That will teach me not to just scan and make assumptions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it work using two tricks, which are explained in the code.

```
use std::mem;

enum Tree<'a> {
    Branch(Box<[Tree<'a>; 2]>),
    Leaf(&'a mut[f32]),
    Placeholder, // it's not very nice hack, but it's required for mem::replace
}

impl<'a> Tree<'a> {
    fn split(&mut self, max: usize) {
        let mut needs_split = false;
        match self {
            &mut Tree::Branch(ref mut trees) => {
                trees[0].split(max);
                trees[1].split(max);
            },
            &mut Tree::Leaf(ref mut leaf) if leaf.len() > max => {
                // Postpone modification of *self. We can't do it now while
                // a part of *self is borrowed
                needs_split = true;
            },
            _ => {}
        }
        if needs_split {
            // move *self into cself, to be able to
            // deconstruct content, while keeping *self not borrowed
            let cself = mem::replace(self, Tree::Placeholder);
            if let Tree::Leaf(leaf) = cself {
                let mid = leaf.len() / 2;
                let (l, r) = leaf.split_at_mut(mid);
                let trees = [Tree::Leaf(l), Tree::Leaf(r)];
                *self = Tree::Branch(Box::new(trees));
            } else {
                unreachable!()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful (and safe!) technique.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to fix the whole case, but I might be able to lead you in the right direction. First, you need to be explicit about the lifetime of `self`:

```
fn split(&'a mut self, max: usize)
```

The next issue is a non-exhaustive match; this can be easily avoided (for now) with the following base case:

```
_ => unimplemented!()
```

Now the issue is that you mutably borrow `trees` twice in the first match arm; this can be solved by using a loop:

```
&mut Tree::Branch(ref mut trees) => {
    for tree in trees.iter_mut() {
        tree.split(max);
    }
}
```

Now you have:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*self` because it is borrowed
  --> <anon>:18:17
   |
14 |             &mut Tree::Leaf(ref mut leaf) if leaf.len() > max => {
   |                             ------------ borrow of `*self` occurs here
...
18 |                 *self = Tree::Branch(Box::new(trees));
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `*self` occurs here
```

This can be avoided by not destructuring the `Leaf` in the match arm and using a helper function:

```
impl<'a> Tree<'a> {
    fn get_trees(&'a mut self, max: usize) -> Option<[Tree<'a>; 2]> {
        if let &mut Tree::Leaf(ref mut leaf) = self {
            if leaf.len() > max {
                let mid = leaf.len() / 2;
                let (l, r) = leaf.split_at_mut(mid);
                Some([Tree::Leaf(l), Tree::Leaf(r)])
            } else {
                None
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
&mut Tree::Leaf(_) => {
    let trees = self.get_trees(max).unwrap(); // safe (under a valid match arm)
    *self = Tree::Branch(Box::new(trees));
}
```

Now comes a bigger problem, because you can't assign to `self` while borrowing from it. I would consider making it `Clone`able (and creating `trees` based on a copy of `self`), but in your case it can't be derived automatically; maybe someone else will have a better idea.

[Full code in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=68bcfcd97aeb183d6c214b660b1bb710&version=stable&backtrace=0)